# Serve static mp4 video with express

Tags: node.js, linux, express

I made a simple node express server serving statically a public directory

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

the public folder contains a mp4 video.

It works great when I try to access the file with chrome on windows but with chrome on ubuntu I can't play the video and I get either no error message or `net::ERR_TIME_OUT` or `ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`, it is totally random.

The node server is running on a VPS with ubuntu and I don't use any reverse proxy for now.